# Append and Remove Multiple Data Attributes to URL with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Having a tuff time figuring this out.  I am building a front-end WooCommerce cart component that will add multiple products to the cart by passing the product ID into the URL.  The URL structure will ultimately look like this `http://cleancolor.staging.wpengine.com/?add-to-cart=2998,3339,2934` where the `2998,3339,2934` are the WooCommerce Product ID's.

Here is a live working version (without the append) http://studiorooster.com/dojo/cleancolor/ - just click on a "5 Pack" or "10 Pack" and select an addon.  I have the product id's appended to the Addon name to the right side list and have the attribute named `data-itemid`

**Here is my html block**

```
<div class="col-md-3 clearfix" id="order_summary_box">
    <div class="summary-box">
        <div class="heading-total">Order Summary : <span class="color-txt" id="order_total"><span>$</span>0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="summary-basic-pack">
            <h5>Whats in Your Bundle</h5>
            <ul class="entree-add" id="entree-add">
                <li id="no-entrees">No Entrees Added</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pack-add" id="pack-add">
                <li id="no-addons">No Addons Selected</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="orderbtn-area">
            <div class="order-btn-cont"><a href="" class="button" id="order_btn_id"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Subscribe Now !</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#get-started').delegate('.check-opt', 'click', function () {
    let cost = '0';
    let itemname = '';
    let first = '';
    let itemid = ''
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        cost = $(this).attr('data');
        itemid = $(this).attr('data-itemid');
        order_additional_options += Number(cost);
        itemname = $(this).attr('value');
        first = itemname.slice(0, itemname.indexOf(" "));
        $("#no-addons").remove();
        $(".pack-add").append("<li data-cost='" + cost + "' data-id='item_" + first + cost + "' data-itemid='" + itemid + "'>" + itemname + itemid + "</li>");
    } else { // minus unchecked value
        cost = $(this).attr('data');
        itemname = $(this).attr('value');
        first = itemname.slice(0, itemname.indexOf(" "));
        order_additional_options -= Number(cost);
        $('[data-id=item_' + first + cost + ']').remove();
    }
    cart_update();
});
// on click order button submit the form

$('#order_btn_id').on("click", function () {
    $('a').attr("href", "http://cleancolor.staging.wpengine.com/?add-to-cart=");
});
```

Comment: so if the user clicks on `#order_btn_id` you want him to be redirected to `http://cleancolor.staging.wpengine.com/?add-to-cart=<<product id from addon>>`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine whether the window has a push stat

Find all elements that are added to the .pack-add and extract their number

Compile a `,` delimited string

The following sections that starts and end with `//*************`
in the snip below should do the trick. Probably you can refactor it into a function.

```
// add and remove check box items on summary
$('#get-started').delegate('.check-opt', 'click', function () {
    let cost = '0';
    let itemname = '';
    let first = '';
    let itemid = ''
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        cost = $(this).attr('data');
        itemid = $(this).attr('data-itemid');
        order_additional_options += Number(cost);
        itemname = $(this).attr('value');
        first = itemname.slice(0, itemname.indexOf(" "));
        $("#no-addons").remove();
        $(".pack-add").append("<li data-cost='" + cost + "' data-id='item_" + first + cost + "' data-itemid='" + itemid + "'>" + itemname + itemid + "</li>");
// ********************* INSERTED CODES
        var all_values=""
    $(".pack-add").children().each(function(){
        all_values+=$(this).attr('data-itemid')+" "

})
    console.log(all_values.trim().replace(" ",","));
    var query_string="?add-to-cart="+all_values.trim().replace(/ /g,",");
    if (history.pushState) {
        var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + query_string;
        window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
     }
// **********************END OF NEW CODES

    } else { // minus unchecked value
        cost = $(this).attr('data');
        itemname = $(this).attr('value');
        first = itemname.slice(0, itemname.indexOf(" "));
        order_additional_options -= Number(cost);
        $('[data-id=item_' + first + cost + ']').remove();
// ********************* INSERTED CODES
        var all_values=""
    $(".pack-add").children().each(function(){
        all_values+=$(this).attr('data-itemid')+" "

})
    console.log(all_values.trim().replace(" ",","));
    var query_string="?add-to-cart="+all_values.trim().replace(/ /g,",");
    if (history.pushState) {
        var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + query_string;
        window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
     }

    }
    cart_update();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great.  I am caught on one thing; after the first append, no commas are added so the last product has a blank space.  I updated the code on the site above if you want to check it out.

Comment: you would like a comma after the last? maybe you can replace query string "var query_string="?add-to-cart="+all_values.trim().replace(" ",",");" with    var query_string="?add-to-cart="+all_values.trim().replace(" ",",")+",";

Comment: Not after the last - I have 3 addons and when I check all three of them, the string looks like `3040,3041 3042` notice the space between #2 and #3?

Comment: I now see the issue answer edited...I simply use regex to replace ALL spaces  see var query_string="?add-to-cart="+all_values.trim().replace(/ /g,",");

Comment: Thats RockStar!!